# Secure file with password in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a Backup-Tool with PowerShell. I'm going to use the robocopy Method to copy the files from one Path to another. Now I want to secure the files with a password so the user can save the backup with a password and if he wants to open up the folder containing the backup he has to type in the password he set before. How can I do that?

I have searched the web so far but all I found was just how to encrypt a string and now how to encrypt a file/folder that the user needs to type in a password

Comment: Welcome to SO, @LC195. People on SO are generally eager to help, but need a bit more information in order to be helpful. Please show us the source code you have tried, what the result was, and any error messages.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can find powershell functions for file encrypt/decrypt here: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/encryptdecrypt/0.8.8/Content/Private%5CEncryptFile.ps1